# Pusher.js sending data to the client

Tags: pusher

I would like to use Pusher.js on the client to send data to the server.

I have done this but I have one unique use case.  I do not want to broadcast this to every other client.  I would like to terminate on the server, possible?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: If you sent data to a pusher channel but no one else was subscribed to that channel then what good would be? Isn't that the only value proposition of Pusher?

Comment: Are you hoping to send data from a client in JavaScript and have your server read it?

Comment: @JasonSperske "Isn't this the only value proposition of Pusher". No. The value of a "managed" service such as Pusher, PubNub, Realtime.co etc. is much more than simply broadcasting data; infrastructure/scaling, developer tools, supported libraries, general support, community, maintenance and service features e.g. WebHooks.

Comment: @user2865490 I think your question needs further clarification. If you want to send data from the server to the client then you could simply make an HTTP request (AJAX). If you want to send this data via Pusher you would need to run a Pusher client on the server.

Comment: @leggetter, what I meant was all of the infrastructure that is skillfully provided by real time messaging services (and I am a huge fan and happy customer of PubNub) is to solve the problem of getting lots of clients to effortlessly send and listen to messages.  Simple ain't easy :)

Comment: Yes.  I use it to broadcast to all the clients connected and its great but sometimes I would like to just send information back to the server.   I have several use case where is required in my application.